# How to document.write javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my javascript object

```
var students = [
    {
        name: "Pavel Ravel",
        track: "CSS, HTML5, jQUery",
        achievements: "145",
        points: "353"
    },
    {
        name: "Steve Jobs",
        track: "MacOS, iOS",
        achievements: "3958735",
        points: "09854"
    },
    {
        name: "Bill Gates",
        track: "Windows",
        achievements: "358798",
        points: "37593"
    },
    {
        name: "Gabe Newel",
        track: "Steam",
        achievements: "5302",
        points: "3052"
    },
    {
        name: "Steve Wozniak",
        track: "Apple 1 and 2",
        achievements: "23562",
        points: "3525632"
    }
];
```

What I should do for document.write variable students? I have created for in loop but it writes only undefined.

```
for ( var studentsList in students ) {
    document.write(studentsList[students]);
}
```

The goal is to write to document this

*name: "Pavel Ravel",
track: "CSS, HTML5, jQUery",
achievements: "145",
points: "353"*

and so on

Comment: `document.write(JSON.stringify(students));`

Comment: You should never be using `document.write()` with plain text (if you use it at all, which generally you should not). It's meant for use with HTML; if you have other forms of text you need to HTML encode them first or you're asking for (possibly-security-compromising) bugs. Consider something like `document.body.textContent += "your text"` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `for/in` loops with arrays as they use strings as the enumerator and will enumerate all properties of the array (beyond just the indexed elements). Use a traditional counting `for` loop or `forEach()`.

Also, unless you are dynamically building new page content into a new `window`, don't use `document.write()` as it requires the page to be built sequentially. Use `console.log()` for testing and DOM injection otherwise.

**Solution 1** (gets the exact output you said you wanted - see comments inline for details):

```js
var students = [
    {
        name: "Pavel Ravel",
        track: "CSS, HTML5, jQUery",
        achievements: "145",
        points: "353"
    },
    {
        name: "Steve Jobs",
        track: "MacOS, iOS",
        achievements: "3958735",
        points: "09854"
    },
    {
        name: "Bill Gates",
        track: "Windows",
        achievements: "358798",
        points: "37593"
    },
    {
        name: "Gabe Newel",
        track: "Steam",
        achievements: "5302",
        points: "3052"
    },
    {
        name: "Steve Wozniak",
        track: "Apple 1 and 2",
        achievements: "23562",
        points: "3525632"
    }
];

var output = []; // Used to hold extracted data

// Loop through the array of objects
for ( var i = 0; i < students.length; ++i ) {
  
  // Loop over the current object use for/in for this
  for(var student in students[i]){
    // In this loop, student will be the property names we enumerate over
    
    // To get the property name, just use the enumerator (student)
    // To get the value of the property, pass that property name to the object
    // which, in this case, is the array element we are already looping over.   
    // Note: This string is put together exactly as your question asked:
    output.push(student + ":" + '"' + students[i][student] + '"');
  }
 
}

// To join all the new array values with a comma
console.log(output.join(","));
```

**Solution 2** (shows how to extract the object property names and the values so you can do whatever you want with them using **[`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** - see comments inline for details):

```js
var students = [
    {
        name: "Pavel Ravel",
        track: "CSS, HTML5, jQUery",
        achievements: "145",
        points: "353"
    },
    {
        name: "Steve Jobs",
        track: "MacOS, iOS",
        achievements: "3958735",
        points: "09854"
    },
    {
        name: "Bill Gates",
        track: "Windows",
        achievements: "358798",
        points: "37593"
    },
    {
        name: "Gabe Newel",
        track: "Steam",
        achievements: "5302",
        points: "3052"
    },
    {
        name: "Steve Wozniak",
        track: "Apple 1 and 2",
        achievements: "23562",
        points: "3525632"
    }
];

// Loop through the array of objects executing the supplied 
// function for each one encountered (the "student" argument
// of the supplied function will refer to each element in the 
// array that is enumerated - individual student objects in
// this case, hence the name "student")
students.forEach(function(student) {
  
  // Loop over the current object. Use for/in or Object.keys() for this
  for(var prop in student){
    // In this loop, student will be the property names we enumerate over
    
    // To get the property name, just use the enumerator (prop)
    // To get the value of the property, pass that property name to the object
    // which, in this case, is the array element we are already looping over.
    console.log(prop + ":" + '"' + student[prop] + '"'); 
  }
 
});
```

Comment: Down vote less than a second after posting?! Get real!

Comment: I'm not sure why people are down voting correct answers...it is annoying though.

Comment: Still down voting the correct answer. Check your egos people.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON.stringify()`:

```js
var students = [
    {
        name: "Pavel Ravel",
        track: "CSS, HTML5, jQUery",
        achievements: "145",
        points: "353"
    },
    {
        name: "Steve Jobs",
        track: "MacOS, iOS",
        achievements: "3958735",
        points: "09854"
    },
    {
        name: "Bill Gates",
        track: "Windows",
        achievements: "358798",
        points: "37593"
    },
    {
        name: "Gabe Newel",
        track: "Steam",
        achievements: "5302",
        points: "3052"
    },
    {
        name: "Steve Wozniak",
        track: "Apple 1 and 2",
        achievements: "23562",
        points: "3525632"
    }
];

document.write(JSON.stringify(students));
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't output what the OP asked for.

Comment: I didn't down vote you, but you asked why you got down voted. Your solution just outputs the entire array. As for mine, it gets the property names and the property values only and will write it any way you like.

Comment: @ScottMarcus read the title of his question: "How to document.write javascript object"...sometimes you have to read between the lines as to what the OP wants. This is how I interpreted his question...

Comment: @ScottMarcus yours still isn't in his exact format he asked for: `name: "Pavel Ravel", track: "CSS, HTML5, jQUery", achievements: "145", points: "353"`...

Comment: The OP showed what he wanted. I don't think your answer addresses that, which is probably why it got down voted. I don't see why you are arguing this point with me. I'm just telling you. Also, check my answer again as it now shows both a generic way to extract the data (which is my reading between the lines as to what I thought the OP wanted) and how to get *exactly* the output the OP asked for.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'm done arguing this with you read the title **How to document.write javascript object**...By your reasoning your answer should have been down voted the entire time until u just updated it.

Comment: *The goal is to write to document this **name: "Pavel Ravel", track: "CSS, HTML5, jQUery", achievements: "145", points: "353"** and so on'* I don't think there is much to argue about. If you can't understand what is being asked, you're going to get down voted.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `<div>` for the output and append the text and the line break tag `<br>`.

```js
var students = [{ name: "Pavel Ravel", track: "CSS, HTML5, jQUery", achievements: "145", points: "353" }, { name: "Steve Jobs", track: "MacOS, iOS", achievements: "3958735", points: "09854" }, { name: "Bill Gates", track: "Windows", achievements: "358798", points: "37593" }, { name: "Gabe Newel", track: "Steam", achievements: "5302", points: "3052" }, { name: "Steve Wozniak", track: "Apple 1 and 2", achievements: "23562", points: "3525632" }];

students.forEach(function (o) {
    this.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Object.keys(o).map(function (k) {
        return k + ': ' + JSON.stringify(o[k]);
    }).join(', ')));
    this.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
}, document.getElementById('out'));
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
students.map(x=>document.write(Object.keys(x).map(y=>` ${y}: "${x[y]}"`)+"<br>"));
```

```js
var students = [
    {
        name: "Pavel Ravel",
        track: "CSS, HTML5, jQUery",
        achievements: "145",
        points: "353"
    },
    {
        name: "Steve Jobs",
        track: "MacOS, iOS",
        achievements: "3958735",
        points: "09854"
    },
    {
        name: "Bill Gates",
        track: "Windows",
        achievements: "358798",
        points: "37593"
    },
    {
        name: "Gabe Newel",
        track: "Steam",
        achievements: "5302",
        points: "3052"
    },
    {
        name: "Steve Wozniak",
        track: "Apple 1 and 2",
        achievements: "23562",
        points: "3525632"
    }
];

students.map(x=>document.write(Object.keys(x).map(y=>` ${y}: "${x[y]}"`)+"<br>"));
```