# generating list of objects using .filter() method javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods

I was studying up on the .filter() method in Javascript. I came across this example online.

```
var heroes = [
        {name: "Batman", franchise: "DC"},
        {name: "Ironman", franchise: "Marvel"},
        {name: "Thor", franchise: "Marvel"},
        {name: "Superman", franchise: "DC"}
    ];

  var marvelHeroes = heroes.filter(function(hero) {
      return hero.franchise == "Marvel";
  })

  document.write(marvelHeroes);
```

I expect to get an array of objects showing only the Marvel heroes. However, when I try to print the results of the marvelHeroes variable, I am getting the following result:

[object Object],[object Object]

Can someone tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: You cannot output an array to the document. Either use `console.log(marvelHeroes)` or `document.body.innerText = JSON.stringify(marvelHeroes);` Closing this.

Comment: Use `document.write(JSON.stringify(marvelHeroes));` and check the output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to document.write javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41472662/how-to-document-write-javascript-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is, you're sending it raw JavaScript objects. As others have pointed out, if you stringify this array, the error disappears. The reason that `[object Object]` shows up is that the browser can only put strings in HTML. So in order to coerce those objects into strings, it uses the `Object#toString` method, which results in each method being turned into a string as `[object Object]`. By using `JSON.stringify` to serialize the objects before writing it to the document, you ensure that the objects are properly represented in string form.

```js
const object = { a: 'a', b: '2', c: 3 };
const stringOne = object.toString();
const stringTwo = JSON.stringify(object);

document.write(stringOne);
document.write(stringTwo);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the JS data structure to a string to view it on the page. For that you use [`stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). Further, to get a nice formatted output, and add the string to a `pre` element with a nice indentation.

```js
var heroes = [{"name":"Batman","franchise":"DC"},{"name":"Ironman","franchise":"Marvel"},{"name":"Thor","franchise":"Marvel"},{"name":"Superman","franchise":"DC"}];

var marvelHeroes = heroes.filter(function(hero) {
  return hero.franchise == "Marvel";
})

const pre = document.querySelector('pre');
pre.textContent = JSON.stringify(marvelHeroes, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to write object, before that you need to stringify it (to json)

```
document.write(JSON.stringify(marvelHeroes));
```

```js
var heroes = [
        {name: "Batman", franchise: "DC"},
        {name: "Ironman", franchise: "Marvel"},
        {name: "Thor", franchise: "Marvel"},
        {name: "Superman", franchise: "DC"}
    ];

  var marvelHeroes = heroes.filter(function(hero) {
      return hero.franchise == "Marvel";
  })

  document.write(JSON.stringify(marvelHeroes));
```